# seleniumで普段使用するchromeを自動操縦した後に全てのサービスに再ログインを求められる。

Tags: python, python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

## 環境

mac os highsierra
Python3.8
selenium
chrome ver.85

## 問題

１：困っている
seleniumで普段使用するchromeのユーザプロファイルを指定して自動操縦した後にchromeを閉じて、起動して手動に切り替えると今までログインしていたサービス（twitter, spotify, スタックオーバフロー等...）に再びログインしなければいけなくなります。
毎回seleniumを使用するたびにログインするのは大変なので、どうしたら毎回ログインしなくてよくなるのでしょうか？

２：困っている
どうして普段のブラウザを自動操縦しているのか？
cookieを普段使用しているブラウザの物を使用したくてこのような設定をしているのですが、手動でログイン後にseleniumで再びアクセスするとログインを求められます。おそらくcookieが共有されてなくて、セッションが保たれていない。
やはりseleniumで起動するchromeと手動で起動するchromeは別物なのでしょうか？

**seleniumの設定コード**

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=###')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile #')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('selenium/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('url')
```

どうか詳しい方よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それらのオプションを何も指定せず(headless?でも無い形で)実行してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: chromeは立ち上がりましたが、ゲストで入ったようなchromeが立ち上がりました。そして手動に切り換えたら、再ログインを必要としました。

Comment: chrome自身がどこからどんな風に起動されたか見てるのかもしれませんね。

Comment: 確かに自動で立ち上げたchromeをそのまま手動で使用してログインしようとすると手動と違い自動でパスワードを入力してくれません。